# How to send cross-domain and get respond

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I would like to set form where i can send some informations to another domain cross-domain and getting response back.

Let say I've the following database table `info`

I would like to set form where i can send some informations to another domain cross-domain and getting response back.

I've made many searching for tutorial but all are without full example to study so this example will helps me a lot.

Let say I've the following database table info

```
---------------------
| ID |  Name  | Age |
---------------------
| 12 |  Dave  | 18  |
---------------------
| 34 |  Eva   | 17  |
---------------------
| 31 | Carry  | 19  |
---------------------
```

Now the HTML page `index.html` on `www.site_1.com` and this form will sent cross-domain both `name` and `age` to `http://www.site_2.com/data.php`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" name="form" method="post">
<fieldset>
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input class="text" id="name" name="name" size="20" type="text" />

<label for="name">Age:</label>
<input class="text" id="age" name="age" size="20" type="text" />

<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>
</fieldset>
</form>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var name = $(this).find("#name").val();
        var age = $(this).find("#age").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            crossdomain: true,
            //data: 'name=' + name + '&age=' + age,
            data: {name : name, age : age},
            url: 'http://www.site_2.com/data.php',
            success: function(data){
                if(data == 1){
                    alert("YES!");
                }else{
                    alert("NO");
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Now on `www.site_2.com` here is the code of `data.php`

```
<?PHP
// Suppose it already connected to DB

// for cross-domain
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
    case 'http://localhost': case 'https://localhost':
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    break;
}

// getting sent informations
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];

// do some query
$a1 = "select id from info where name = '$name'";
$query = mysql_query($a1) or die(mysql_error());
$get = mysql_fetch_array($query);

// get the id
$id = $get['id'];

// i want it to send it back
echo $id;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you code works if your `www.site_1.com` is `localhost`. you will get a plain text response `1` (if the id is 1). if you have a lot data to return
you can encode it as json using `json_encode` in server, and decode it using `JSON.parse` in client. using `echo` to send data back is fine. everything you `echo` will be in the response body

if it is not working in your machine, there are some reasons i can think about

1. `$.ajax` part has some trouble. i only tested the server part using different client code.
2. your server got some trouble in database operations.
3. your client code is not in `localhost` domain, so the part for set header to allow CORS is never executed and you will see error in console like this `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.site_2.com/info.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.site_1.com' is therefore not allowed access.`